# passing data frame name as command line argument

Tags: r

I am a novice to R and hence need some help

I am trying to generalise the functionality where I can run the same code on multiple data frame objects which are already available in the workspace. Hence I want to pass the data frame as command line argument. I am passing the same as below:

```
Rscript command_test.R my_data_frame
```

Within the script file, when I use args[1], it doesn't understand that its a data frame object and hence not performing any operations on the data frame. For example, I am just doing a simple operation like `print(colnames((args[1]))` to print the column names from the data frame. But it responds with NULL

I tried with `as.data.frame, as.name` etc. However, none of these helped to understand it as a data frame.

This must be something very trivial, but I couldn't figure it out. Hence need your expert advise on this at the earliest. Please help out! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a variable given its name, which is done using the `get` function.

Here's a short example showing it in action:

```
a <- data.frame(a = c(1))
b <- data.frame(b = c(1))
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
data.frame.name <- args[1]
print(colnames(get(data.frame.name)))
```

If the script is called `foo.R`, then we can get the following output:

```
> Rscript foo.R a
[1] "a"
>  Rscript foo.R b
[1] "b"
>  Rscript foo.R c
NULL
```

Hope this helps.